# Proof about rational roots and polynomials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all integers and $\xi = m/n$ is a rational solution of the equation
$$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0  $$
then $\xi$ is an integer.
Hints: (i) You may assume that $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. (ii) Substitute $\xi$ into the equation and multiply by $n^3$ to clear denominators. (iii) Show that $n \mid m^3$.

Approach:

showing $n|m^3$ is very easy

Once you have it, consider $n\mid m^3$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$,
$n\mid m^3 \Rightarrow n\mid m*m^2$ but $\gcd(m,n)=1$, so $n\mid m^2$. Similarly $n\mid m$ which implies that $m=nk$, so $m/n=nk/n=k$.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your work is correct. Good job!

Comment: Now I think that it's wrong because the gcd(m,n)=1 so how can n dividides m?

Comment: maybe I can complete my argument by saying $n|1$ therefore n=1

Comment: @TheMathNoob If you want, you can show $n=1$, but your argument is perfectly fine as it is now. $\gcd(m, n)=1$ and $n \mid m$ do not contradict each other because of the $n=1$ case, so your argument is perfectly valid.